# set angularjs global configuration for timezone

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs

i want to know is there any option to set a global configuration for timezone provided by angularjs . I googled lot  but i cannot find as is possible .  In my application i have to pass a time to server and it will stored in mysql db . While saving time in server its stored as different time(+8.30) , I'm using +530 time zone . what they way ill handle this issue ?

My form sent as a datetime to server like as follows

```
2015-01-13T13:45:00.000Z
```

Without any filter how to achieve this because i am using many  date-time field , it will complicated if use in every place

Answer (score 1):

In general using global object is bad practice in javascript but angular has a nice feature named constant. every module has a constant feature that you can store const value in there and inject it everywhere you need to use it. for example you can follow this approach :

```
angular.module('myApp.config', [])
.constant('TIME_ZONE','value');

angular.module('myApp.controllers', ['myApp.config'])
.controller('ListCtrl', ['$scope', 'TIME_ZONE', function($scope, time_zone) {
 $scope.time = time_zone;
}]);
```

you can get more information for module features from this link:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module

Answer (score 0):

You can declare your App and then configure timezone for your app using `constants`, you can set as many as you want.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.constant("myConfig", {
    "TIMEZONE": "SomeTimezone"
});

myApp.controller('myController', ['myConfig', function(myConfig) {
    // Access your global timezone using myConfig.TIMEZONE 
}]);
```